# Draw on transparent background

Tags: opencv

I want to draw a white circle on transparent background using OpenCV, I use code for this:

```cpp
cv::Mat m(500, 500, CV_8UC4, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0, 0));
cv::circle(m, cv::Point(250, 250), 100, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255, 255), 10, cv::LINE_AA);
cv::imwrite("img.png", m);
```

But as result I have circle with grey outline on transparent background.
[image: result image]

Outline color depends on "color" of transparent background - if I draw circve over

```cpp
cv::Mat m(500, 500, CV_8UC4, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255, 0));
```

the outline is red.

[image]

How to avoid this and draw circle without outline?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `cv::LINE_8` instead of `cv::LINE_AA`. The point is that `cv::LINE_AA` produces smooth color transition at the boundary which usually makes the image smoother, but in this case looks like an outline because the background is transparent.

Alternatively you may use

```
cv::Mat m(500, 500, CV_8UC4, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255, 0));
```

and preserve smooth transparency gradient at the boundary given by `cv::LINE_AA`, but if you draw something else non-white on top of it with `cv::LINE_AA`, you will still get a white outline around it.